# Get the average of ratings from testimonials that belong to user's several portfolio items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My first statement is, you might want to suggest a different approach on how I should be doing this. Your suggestion is welcome and thank you for helping me out but I will need a lot of time to change stuff right now as it relies on other implementations. So for now, I will try to stick on fixing what I was already given.

So, Users have portfolio items (has_many :portfolios). Portfolio items have many testimonials (has_many :testimonials) and belongs_to :user. Also, the testimonials belongs_to :portfolios.
The testimonials have a column in their db table named "rating".

What I need to do is, in the user's view show action, get the average of all ratings from testimonials (placed on user's portfolio's items) and just show it there (/users/id) as a single average for the user (for all of its ratings on portfolio items through the testimonials). For example a rating could be: User rating: 4.7/5.

What I've done so far:
I grabbed the user's portfolios in the controllers show action (@portfolios = @user.portfolios) and then I tried with several way to grab the testimonials as objects so I can extract their rating, add up everything and get the average.

Is this possible? (If you need any other information please let me know and I will add it)

Any tip or guidance to move on would be really helpful.

Comment: you want all portfolio items testimonial or an individual portfolio item testimonials

Comment: Individual for each user to be shown on his/her show page /users/id

Comment: Testimonial.where(portfolio_id: @user.portfolios.pluck(:id) ) gives you all testimonial for this user

Comment: let me know if this does not help or not the result you want to achieve

Comment: have a look at Testimonial.where(portfolio_id: @user.portfolios.pluck(:id) ).average(:rating).to_f

Comment: omg you are awesome! thank you very much mate. I was having troubles getting the sum and had no clue whats going on. saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting all testimonials for a user assuming that @user is holding a user object

```
Testimonial.where(portfolio_id: @user.portfolios.pluck(:id) )
```

or make a relation between user and testimonial such as

```
User has_many :testimonials, through: :portfolios
```

and then `@user.testimonials`

(edit: syntax error on through)